# passing data from view to controller in cakephp

Tags: javascript, arrays, cakephp

I have an javascript array variable in my view file , how can i send the array to different controller ?
this is html code:

```
<button id=<?php echo $key ?> onclick="movebutton(this)" class='li'><?php echo $officers['Officer']['name'] ?> </button>
```

and this is my javascript code:

```
function movebutton(elem){
    var teamMember=new Array();
    if( $(elem).parent().attr("class") == "officers_list" ){
        $(elem).detach().appendTo('.add_member');
         teamMember.push($(elem));
    }
    else{
        $(elem).detach().appendTo('.officers_list'); 
        teamMember.pop($(elem));

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass any data to controller using ajax -:

Get values you want to a javascript variable and check a sample ajax

```
 $.ajax({
        dataType: "html",
        type: "POST",
        evalScripts: true,
        url: '<?php echo Router::url(array( 
        'controller'=>'controller','action'=>'action'));?>',
        data: ({type:variable-value }),
        success: function (data){
              return true;
            // $("#div").html(data);

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

To pass data from view to controller:

1. You can use form but in form your data won't be sent as an array
2. Using ajax

.

```
var data = {
    val1 = '<?php echo $string ?>';
    val2 = '<?php echo $number ?>';
}

$.post( 'controller/action', data , function(response) {
    if (response == true) {
        // Do this
    } else {
        // Do that
    }
});
```